# Simplify division of integrals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Given the division of two integrals like

$$
I = \frac{\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \, dx}{\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}
$$

with $f$, $g$ being real-valued functions.

Is it possible to simplify this further? I.e. is it possible to compute this using only one integration instead of two? I am asking because I want to solve this efficiently with numeric solvers.

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: not generally but you can bound it using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mbox{How about}\quad
{\int_{a}^{b}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\mrm{g}\pars{x}\,\dd x \over
\int_{a}^{b}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
\left.\totald{}{\lambda}
\ln\pars{\int_{a}^{b}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\expo{\lambda\mrm{g}\pars{x}}\dd x}
\right\vert_{\ \lambda\ =\ 0}\ {\Large ?}.
\end{align}

Comment: Hm this looks interesting but I wounder how I can calculate the derivative since I want to evaluate this numerically... If I use a finite difference, then I would still have to evaluate the integral two times, right?

Comment: @SampleTime I'm afraid you're quite right. I'll think about it.